# how to define the one of composite key to the certain entity in jpa?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm curious how to define the one field that an entity has to the certain entity.
you can see the below two tables ddl.

```sql
create table `rank_season` (
       `start_date` date not null,
        `user_id` varchar(255) not null,
        `prize_top` decimal(19,2),
        primary key (`start_date`, `user_id`)
    ) engine=InnoDB;

create table `user` (
       `user_id` varchar(255) not null,
       `reg_date` datetime(6),
       primary key (`user_id`)
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

I use the entities like this.
but I would like to change the field, user_id, to User entity.
I tried to do several times but it didn't work.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(GameSeason.Pk.class)
public class GameSeason {

    @Id
    private LocalDate startDate;
    @Id
    private String userId; // todo: change to User entity
    private BigInteger prizeTop;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    public static class Pk implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private LocalDate startDate;
        @Id
        private String userId;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

    @Id
    private String userId;
    private LocalDateTime regDate;
}
```

---

I made it like this.
just plus related entity field to `GameSeason`

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(GameSeason.Pk.class)
public class GameSeason {

    @Id
    private LocalDate startDate;
    @Id
    private String userId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
    private BigInteger prizeTop;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    public static class Pk implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private LocalDate startDate;
        @Id
        private String userId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your SQL and Spring code. In `create table 'user'` SQL you define `gid` as the primary key, but actually, your primary key is `user_id`!!  However, for your purpose first, add the foreign key constraints:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
```

To the database as:

```
create table `rank_season` (
       `start_date` date not null,
        `user_id` varchar(255) not null,
        `prize_top` decimal(19,2),
        primary key (`start_date`, `user_id`),
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB;
```

And in your Java code add this annotation on top of the `userId` property in order to define `ManyToOne` relation:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

Class `GameSeason` complete code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(GameSeason.Pk.class)
public class GameSeason {

    @Id
    private LocalDate startDate;
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    private BigInteger prizeTop;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    public static class Pk implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private LocalDate startDate;
        @Id
        private String userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a ddl error, thank to find that :) btw GameSeason.userId is still string object.  I would like to use the object to User entity

Comment: @JoonseoLee Ohh! That's my mistake, I update my answer. Just simply change String to `User` class.

Comment: @JoonseoLee Also a minor typo I fixed about `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: unfortunately, it comes out an error `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to find properties (userId) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.joonseo.sample.entity.GameSeason`

Comment: ahhhh I have made it! I just added related user entity field then it works. thanks you anyway :))